# NameError name 'var' not defined in IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code which works fine:

```
for index, row in dfcodes.iterrows():
    # for each security code identify those with 3 down candles and narrowing raneg for first 3 days of 6 day set
    scode=row['Security_Code']

    tdate='2016-01-15'
    df=fetch_last(scode,tdate,6)
    dfreverse=df.sort('TradeDate', ascending=True)

    #look for 3 consecutive down candles with narrowing range and then 2 up candles
    dfdownbars=dfreverse.head(5)
    ncnt=1

    for index,row in dfdownbars.iterrows():
        otmp = row['Opening_Price']
        ctmp = row['Closing_Price']
        rtmp = abs(row['Opening_Price'] - row['Closing_Price'])
        dtmp = row['TradeDate']
        if ctmp<otmp and ncnt==1:
            o1 = otmp
            c1 = ctmp
            r1 = rtmp
            d1 = dtmp
            ncnt+=1
        elif ctmp<otmp and otmp<o1 and ctmp<c1 and rtmp<=r1 and ncnt==2:
            o2 = otmp
            c2 = ctmp
            r2 = rtmp
            d2 = dtmp
            ncnt += 1
        elif ctmp<otmp and otmp<o2 and rtmp<=r2 and ncnt==3:
            o3 = otmp
            c3 = ctmp
            r3 = rtmp
            d3 = dtmp
            ncnt += 1
        else:
            break
```

However, as soon as I add a 4th `elif` I get the following error:

```
elif ctmp > otmp and ctmp > c3 and ncnt == 4:
NameError: name 'c3' is not defined
```

i.e. the erroneous code now looks like this:

```
for index, row in dfcodes.iterrows():
    # for each security code identify those with 3 down candles and narrowing raneg for first 3 days of 6 day set
    scode=row['Security_Code']

    tdate='2016-01-15'
    df=fetch_last(scode,tdate,6)
    dfreverse=df.sort('TradeDate', ascending=True)

    #look for 3 consecutive down candles with narrowing range and then 2 up candles
    dfdownbars=dfreverse.head(5)
    ncnt=1

    for index,row in dfdownbars.iterrows():
        otmp = row['Opening_Price']
        ctmp = row['Closing_Price']
        rtmp = abs(row['Opening_Price'] - row['Closing_Price'])
        dtmp = row['TradeDate']
        if ctmp<otmp and ncnt==1:
            o1 = otmp
            c1 = ctmp
            r1 = rtmp
            d1 = dtmp
            ncnt+=1
        elif ctmp<otmp and otmp<o1 and ctmp<c1 and rtmp<=r1 and ncnt==2:
            o2 = otmp
            c2 = ctmp
            r2 = rtmp
            d2 = dtmp
            ncnt += 1
        elif ctmp<otmp and otmp<o2 and rtmp<=r2 and ncnt==3:
            o3 = otmp
            c3 = ctmp
            r3 = rtmp
            d3 = dtmp
            ncnt += 1
        elif ctmp > otmp and ctmp > c3 and ncnt==4:  # first up candle after 3 downs
            o4 = otmp
            c4 = ctmp
            r4 = rtmp
            ncnt += 1
        else:
            break

    cnt -= 1
```

Can anyone tell me why the variable `c3` is not recognised in the final `elif` statement when all the variables `c1` - `c3` were recognised before I added the final `elif`?
By the way, I am iterating through a pandas dataframe

Comment: Yes, `c3` is only defined in another `elif` block. Since only **one** block in a `if ... elif .. else` statement will ever be executed, you can't use names that only are assigned to in one of those blocks in the test for another.

Comment: because, if that `elif` was reached, that means, the condition above it was not satisfied. Implying that `c3` was never declared.

Comment: That `o1` and `o2` don't throw errors is because Python won't even look at later test conditions if an earlier already matched. So if `ctmp<otmp and ncnt==1` matches, it doesn't matter that `o1` and `o2` are not yet set.

Comment: I must say I find your code structure to be very hard to follow. Are you trying to reference preceding rows in the frame? Then just use a list or queue to store a few preceding rows first, and not use so many temporary variables.

Comment: Hi guys - thks very much for responses. All makes sense. I'm just a bit rusty, having not coded for many years.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:  You will probably work if you check `ncnt` first:

```
if ncnt==4 and ctmp > otmp and ctmp > c3:
```

For a longer answer, you must first accept that you are doing something a bit tricky and unusual. You are defining names inside the `else` clauses and trusting that your program will run those cluses to define the names before they are checked later in the code.

That is, in the first iteration of your for loop, you hit this line:

```
  if ctmp<otmp and ncnt==1:
```

because it is true you run the code to define new variables `o1`, `c1`, and `r1`.   If the condition were false on the first iteration, you would hit this line next:

```
  elif ctmp<otmp and otmp<o1 and ctmp<c1 and rtmp<=r1 and ncnt==2:
    o2 = otmp
```

Python would start looking up variables, try to get the value of `o1` and promptly give you the `NameError: name 'o1' is not defined` exception.

There are two real options:

1. Define all the names before you use them, probably setting them to 0.   This is the preferred method and avoids having you stalked by people tasked with maintaining your code years down the line.
2. Carefully check your state first.   This code is a little state machine with the current state noted by `ncnt`.  If your code checked that it were in the correct state first, you would never reference the bad variable.   So better code would rename `ncount` and start your `if` statement with `if nState == 3 and o3 > something...`.   As soon as the
   `nState` is wrong, the `if` statement will stop without looking at variables that don't exist yet.

Comment: Thk you Charles. All makes sense now. Haven't coded for a while so not thinking like I should.